# How can i reproduce the bird to catapult animation in angry birds?

Tags: unity, c#, animation, game-mechanics

I've seen tutorials on producing an angry birds like game but non of them explain how to get the next bird on the catapult after the current bird is shot. Also how would i go about doing this if the catapult could change position and i want to get the next bird on the catapult taking into account that the birds are not all in the same position.[image]

Comment: What should that animation look like? (Assume your reader lacks a photographic memory of playing Angry Birds, and you'll widen the pool of users who can help you)

Answer (score 1):

1)make an empty object and place it where you want to shot your bird of
2)make a reference in your script to this object use its position...
3)use code like this:

```
void ShootBird()
{
   //start position is the position of your object
   GameObject newBird = Instanciate(birdPrefab, startPosition, startRotation);
   //do stuff with your newBird object e.g apply forces etc. 
}
```

Also if you wanna move the next bird into the catapult simply get a reference to it and let it move towards your start position. There are already asked questions which should answer how to move objects to a point.

if you have a specific question go ahead and ask...
next time describe your question more precisely. You´ll get better answers